# ReactDOM.render rendering page

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

New to ReactJS,
Can not find out why this page is not showing anything -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

            <script src="react.16.8.6.development.js"></script>
            <script src="react-dom.16.8.6.development.js"></script>
            <script src="babel.7.5.4.min.js"></script>
        </head>

        <body>
            <div id="container"></div>

            <script type="text/babel">

                class MyClass extends React.Componet{
                    render() {
                        return(<h1>Hello React Componets!</h1>);
                    }
                }

                ReactDOM.render(
                    <h1>MyClass</h1>,
                    document.getElementById('container')
                );
            </script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

I am getting error in console -

VM43:19 Uncaught TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function at _inherits (:19:113)
    at :26:3
    at :42:2

Comment: `React.Componet` caught my eye... :) (should be `Component`)

Comment: Thanks.
is there any way that can catch this kind of error?

Comment: It's tricky with things like this. JavaScript interpreters can't really figure out that it's a typo, it just sees an undefined value. I also notice you've got the class itself in your `ReactDOM.render` call - `<h1>MyClass</h1>`. In order to properly render your component, you should treat it like an HTML tag - e.g. `<MyClass />`. Otherwise you won't get the result you want.

Comment: Thanks.
Yes, <MyClass />   I already made it.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try these code:

```
<script type="text/babel">

    class MyClass extends React.Component{
        render() {
            return(<h1>Hello React Componets!</h1>);
        }
    }

    ReactDOM.render(
        <h1><MyClass/></h1>,
        document.getElementById('container')
    );
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is here,

```
<h1>MyClass</h1>, //This is not a react component, this will only print `MyClass` as text on page
```

Just change,

```
ReactDOM.render(
     <h1>MyClass</h1>,
     document.getElementById('container')
);
```

to this,

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <MyClass />,
    document.getElementById('container')
);
```

**Note:** Correct the typo in your code,
`class MyClass extends React.Componet` should be `class MyClass extends React.Component{`

[Demo](https://jsbin.com/tanogewata/edit?html,output)